# When i read form file in python operatior == returns false always

Tags: python, file

I have a file and i trying read line by line from it and if my 16 last character of each line was `profile picture` do something. but operator always return false.

```
f = open("filename.txt", "r")
count = 0
f.readline()
while True:
    chunk = f.readline()
    mystr = chunk[-16:]
    aa= "profile picture";
    if mystr == aa:  ----------------------------->this line always return false 
        name.append("@"+f.readline())
        count += 1
    else:
        # print(mystr +"\n"+"profile picture" +"\n"+mystr=="profile picture")
        print(mystr is ' profile picture')
    if chunk=='':
        break
```

myfile is something like this :

```
m.m_deading profile picture
Ali
m.m_deading's profile picture
m.test
Ali
m.m_deading's profile picture
Ali
m.m_deading's profile picture
m.test
Ali
m.m_deading's profile picture
m.m_deadafafsing
Ali
```

Even i've tried `is` but still returned false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried to print the output of `chunk[-16:]`, you will see what the problem is. There is a space character in that chuck.

```py
>>> chunk = "m.m_deading's profile picture"
>>> chunk[-16:]
' profile picture'
```

But if some lines of your file contain trailing spaces also, there might be a different kind of problem. Here is what happens if you have 2 trailing spaces in the line.

```py
>>> chunk = "m.m_deading's profile picture  "
>>> chunk[-16:]
'rofile picture  '
```

So there might be 2 cases that your program will fail due to trailing and leading space issues. So my suggestion is to make sure you don't have trailing spaces in your file. You can do that by,

```py
chunk = f.readline().strip()
```

If you print the value of `chunk` you will see no trailing or leading spaces now. Then you can extract the `profile picture` part.

```py
mystr = chunk[-15:]
```

If you get `16` characters, you are getting a space character also. But now you will get only the `profile picture` part from the line.

So the final code is like this.

```py
f = open("filename.txt", "r")
count = 0
f.readline()
while True:
    chunk = f.readline().strip()
    mystr = chunk[-15:]
    
    # You can remove the redundant `aa` variable that was here
    if mystr == "profile picture":
        name.append("@"+f.readline())
        count += 1
    else:
        # print(mystr +"\n"+"profile picture" +"\n"+mystr=="profile picture")
        print(mystr is ' profile picture')
    if chunk=='':
        break
```

And there are some other ways to deal with it also.

```py
chunk = f.readline()
    
if "profile picture" in chunk:
    ...
```

This method will check whether there is the string `profile picture` is in the line you read from the file. But this will return `true` if the `profile picture` was in the middle of the line too.

```py
chunk = f.readline().strip()
    
if chunk.endswith("profile picture"):
    ...
```

This way it will check whether the line is ending with the string `profile picture`. So you have to make sure there are no trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There is whitespace at the end of the profile picture string.  You could use .strip() to get rid of it.  Since `name` is not defined in your posted code I commented it out.

After this runs you can `print(count)` to confirm it found 4 of them.

```
f = open("filename.txt", "r")
count = 0
f.readline()
while True:
    chunk = f.readline()
    mystr = chunk[-16:]

    if mystr.strip() == 'profile picture': 
#         name.append("@"+f.readline())
        count += 1
    else:
        pass
    if chunk=='':
```